# Facebook Graph API private_replies with page access token throws an error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to send private replies as a page with the Graph API:

```
FB.api( '/' + id + '/private_replies', 'post', 

    { message: message, access_token: token }, function(res) {}
);
```

The comment id is fine. The access token has been generated correctly. I have read_page_mailboxes permission. Despite all that, the API throws back this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10903) This user cant reply to this activity",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10903,
    "fbtrace_id": "BW3yOdmwnhi"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure you used a page access token to make the request?

Comment: I did. I just found out what was wrong. I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 4):

The problem appears to be the fact that I tried to reply to my own comments. That is not allowed. Only comments from others are allowed to reply to. Also, once replied to, the comment cannot be replied to ever again. That will throw a (different) error as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered the same problem. The reason might be your page is not published yet.

Comment: I had the same problem. Unpublished test pages don't work.